# How to prevent text file creation by wget in cron job run?

Tags: linux, cron

I am using bellow to run a page every hour in my Virtualmin installed on CentOS 7

```
wget https://domain.tld/index.php?page=cron > /dev/null 2>&1
```

but it creates below files every hour when cron run

```
index.php?page=cron
index.php?page=cron.1
index.php?page=cron.2
```

etc.

Please let me know how to avoid creation of these file.

Comment: You are fetching a web page, but you don't want to actually store it?

Comment: Yes, I don't need output of the page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`wget`, by default, saves the fetched web page in a file whose name corresponds to the document at the end of the URL (it does not send it to its standard output).  If that file already exists, it adds a number to the end of the name.

If you don't want to save the document, then specify that you'd like to save it in `/dev/null`:

```
wget -O /dev/null 'https://domain.tld/index.php?page=cron' >/dev/null 2>&1
```

or

```
wget --output-document=/dev/null --quiet 'https://domain.tld/index.php?page=cron'
```

It's also a good idea to quote the URL as URLs sometimes contain characters that may be interpreted a filename globbing character or command terminators by the shell (like `&` and `[` and `]` etc.).

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't with cron. This is `wget`'s default behavior. To make it redirect to standard out (so you can then sink that output to `/dev/null`), use `wget -O-`. And, you probably *also* want `-q`. So:

```
wget -qO- 'https://domain.tld/index.php?page=cron' > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I don't really recommend this approach, though. What if there's an error? It's better to make a small script which checks that the result is an http 200 code, and that the contents are as expected.

Comment: Thank you for reply and recommendation, actually errors are handled somewhere else so I don't need any kind of output at all. Can you tell me what is -q here?

Comment: @DMP `-q` is the same as `--quiet` (see `man wget`).